# Mailboxer error "unknown attribute 'delivery_method' for Mailboxer::Receipt."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

Anyone come across this error in mailboxer? Was working fine for the past weeks, but suddenly I get this error each time I send a message. Has anyone had this and how did you handle it? I'm working on Rails 4

```
Error: unknown attribute 'delivery_method' for Mailboxer::Receipt.
```

Comment: this might help? https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/391

Comment: That really did help! Just a summary for those facing this issue:
1. Run `rails g mailboxer:install` to generate the migration `_delivery_tracking_info_to_mailboxer_receipts` 
2. when the prompt to overwrite `config/initializers/mailboxer.rb` comes up, enter `N` to skip it
3. Run `rake db:migrate`

restart server and it should be ok.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i solved this error in my code by adding an exception handling in my code.
if anyone encounters this error :“unknown attribute 'delivery_method' for Mailboxer::Receipt.” while using mailboxer in rails 4.2.2, you can try this:

add an exception handling code in the part you send_message

```
       begin
        conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, body,subject).conversation

        rescue  

        end
```